# Unable to get formvalues in onSubmit function in google script

Tags: google-apps-script

I am getting null for   Logger.log(responses)

I have added the trigger also but it is not working.

```
// Triggered when a form is submitted
function onSubmit(e) {
Logger.log('new function shivani sdsad');
   Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));
   
   var form = FormApp.openById('1NrBqulJV--9xu119AHLq3ivpKZMLX742vNiIKfYccd8');
   var response = form.getResponses();
   var lo = response[response.length-1];
   Logger.log(response);
   

  // Get the responses from the form submission
  var responses = e.values;
  //formValues = e.values;

  // Store the formValues in script properties
  //PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty('formValues', JSON.stringify(formValues));
  Logger.log('shivani here check the responses new page');
  
  Logger.log(responses);  Logger.log('shivani');

   
}`
```

Comment: Perhaps you have enabled the wrong trigger.  There are two on form submit trigger.  One is for the spreadsheet and the other is for the form

Comment: Thanks it worked, i had to go to AppScript via GoogleExcel rather google form else it does not work

Comment: Glad it worked but I don't completely understand your explanation